# are atomic operations toothless in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

As per the [**atomic_ops.txt**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/atomic_ops.txt) in the Linux kernel,

```
all users of atomic_t should treat atomic_read() and atomic_set() as simple
C statements that may be reordered or optimized away entirely by the compiler
or processor, and explicitly invoke the appropriate compiler and/or memory
barrier for each use case.  Failure to do so will result in code that may
suddenly break when used with different architectures or compiler
optimizations, or even changes in unrelated code which changes how the
compiler optimizes the section accessing atomic_t variables.

*** YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED! ***
```

If you have to use barriers anyways then what is the use ?

Comment: I think this means that if there exists an hardware mechanism which ensures the atomicity of atomic_read() and atomic_set(), then no memory barrier is needed. However is there is no such mechanism, it is not guaranteed that these functions will work as expected. Thus for portability reasons you should use memory barriers (which will be removed by the compiler if useless?). I didn't experimented with this although.

Comment: I think at least we don't have to bother using things like mutex or semaphores, which could cost more time than atomic operations with memory barriers.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `atomic_t` and 'normal' variables is that the former allows both atomic updates (i.e., other threads see either the old or the new value, but no intermediate state) and atomic read-and-update operations.
In other words, `atomic_t` allows multiple threads to access the *same* variable.

Memory barriers are needed to handle dependencies between *different* variables.